# Dynamically creating ui:ouputDate during aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

parent.cmp

```
<aura:iteration var="column" items="{!v.columns}" >
    <c:myCmp myValue="{!column.property}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

myCmp.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="myValue" type="String" access="global" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
{!v.body}
```

in myCmpController.js

```
var componentBody = component.get('v.body');
var val = component.get('v.myValue');
$A.createComponent('ui:outputDate', {
    "format": 'MM/dd/yyyy',
    "value": val
}, function(thisCmp, status, errorMessage) {
    if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
        componentBody.push(thisCmp);
        component.set('v.body', componentBody);
    } else {
        console.log('errorMessage --> ', errorMessage);
    }
});
```

This was working until sometime yesterday afternoon. It works with ui:outputText. Does Lockerservice block creating ui:outputDate in aura:iteration?

Comment: No, you can create any arbitrary component that you'd like, as long as you have access to it. Do you get an error message in your console?

Comment: @sfdcfox no, and what's all the more curious is I just tried this in my developer org and it was functioning as expected.

Comment: No, LockerService does not explicitly block ui:outputDate in aura:interation. What doesn't work? What is the `thisCmp` value in the `createComponent` callback? What is the `val` param set to? Does the same `createComponent` call work outside the iteration?

Comment: @TrevorBliss `val` is set to 2017-01-01, `thisCmp` is the component `$A.createComponent` just created, see the docs for more on that. The piece that doesn't work is that the value disappears. It creates the span HTML element, which has `class="uiOutputDate"` , but there is no content between the span tags. And yes, when the same code block is used outside of the `aura:iteration` it works.

Comment: @JakeRichter Having trouble reproducing this. Are you sure `val` is the string "2017-01-01" when `createComponent` is called? I must be missing something here.